# Input sound built in mic lower when headphones are plugged on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, microphone, avaudiosession

I have an app that record by the built in mic of the iPhone even if headphones are plugged.
To do that I used :

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

session.setPreferredInput(session.availableInputs[0] as! AVAudioSessionPortDescription, error: nil)
```

The problem is that when headphones are plugged, the voice of the user is recorded by the built in mic but at a lower level that if no headphones are plugged. We almost don't here his voice.

I tried to print the gain of the input with and without headphones but in both case it is at 1.0, the maximum.

Any idea from where it can come ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code which may be very helpful:-

```
func setInputGain(gain: Float) {
  let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
  if audioSession.inputGainSettable {
    var error : NSErrorPointer = nil
    let success = audioSession.setInputGain(gain, error: error)
    if success {
      println("\(error)")
    }
  }
  else {
    println("Cannot set input gain")
  }
}
```

I have also integrated this in my app too from this [Source](https://medium.com/@maximbilan/ios-how-to-control-microphone-input-gain-bc43fc44c8#.wfp82v2dr)

Comment: Each time the console print me "Cannot set input gain" :/ But whatever, the input gain is always 1.0 when I print it, headphones plugged or not.